# Macbook - Select individual files with Keyboard only

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, finder, shortcut

Is there a way to navigate through a list of files and select individual files (like you would normally do with command + click) but using only the keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

I could do it using arrows and holding on SHIFT key; however, you could only select immediately near files. Therefore you are able to select as many (graphically) adjacent files you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for some situations this is perfect. It seems like theres no real way to select files in any position w/o using the mouse.

Comment: @Sandro if it somehow helped you, please upvote the answer (and possibly mark as accepted) ;)